# Cannot modify 1d numpy array passed as argument with loop

Tags: arrays, numpy, loops, numba

I am having a headache with a numba loop and a 1d numpy array and I cannot seem to find an explanation.
Basically, my goal is to pass to modify a numpy array in parallel with numba loop using a function both passed as arguments. It works well with a 2d numpy array but for some reasons, it does not with a simple 1d numpy array. This is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

size = 10


# Define a 1d numpy array
vec_test_1 = np.zeros(size)

# Fill the 1d array with values
for i in range(size):
    vec_test_1[i] = float(i)


# Function that modifies and element
@nb.jit(nopython = True)
def func1(xyz):
    xyz = xyz + 2.47


# Loop with numba to modify all elements of the array
@nb.jit(nopython = True, parallel = True)
def loop_numba(vec, func):
    for i in nb.prange(len(vec)):
        func(vec[i])



loop_numba(vec_test_1, func1)
```

The vec_test_1 is unchanged after this loop:

```
array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

when it should be:

```
array([ 2.47,  3.47,  4.47,  5.47,  6.47,  7.47,  8.47,  9.47, 10.47,
   11.47])
```

What surprises me is that it works well when the array that is passed as argument is a 2d array. I am able to modify all its element with the numba loop.

Could anyone help me to understand this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a return value since you make a copy of the individual elements when passing to the function.

*Explanation:* Found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-are-arguments-passed-by-value-or-by-reference-in-python#:%7E:text=If%20you%20pass%20immutable%20arguments,language%20are%20passed%20by%20reference.).

Basically: you pass a single, immutable element to the function, so it is passed by copy (a copy is created, which is changed in the function). If you do it with a 2D array, to python this is a **mutable** object, so it is passed by reference. If you operate on it now, the underlying reference is changed, and this is visible in the result outside of the function.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

size = 10

# Define a 1d numpy array
vec_test_1 = np.arange(size, dtype=np.float32)

# Function that modifies and element
@nb.jit(nopython = True)
def func1(xyz):
    xyz = xyz + 2.47
    return xyz

# Loop with numba to modify all elements of the array
@nb.jit(nopython = True, parallel = True)
def loop_numba(vec, func):
    for i in nb.prange(len(vec)):
        vec[i] = func(vec[i])

loop_numba(vec_test_1, func1)

In [2]: vec_test_1
Out[2]: 
array([ 2.47,  3.47,  4.47,  5.47,  6.47,  7.47,  8.47,  9.47, 10.47,
       11.47], dtype=float32)
```

---

Also: I changed your vector initialization to `np.arange(size, dtype=float)` to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dorian ! Now it works. I understand the reason. Nevertheless, I must confess that it is strange to me that an element of a 2D array is considered as mutable whereas an element of a 1D array is considered ad immutable.

Comment: an element of a 2d array is a 1D array, which is mutable. An element of a 1D array is an integer/float, and that is immutable.

Comment: I had to fight with that a lot since I learned programming in C++, but yes, sometimes it's weird.